# How can I solve probability questions using the lebesgue integral?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Here are examples of questions I found in Google. I was curious about whether they can be solved via lebesgue integration and how. Examples:

A random number selector can only select one of the nine integers 1, 2, ..., 9, and it makes these selections with equal probability. Determine the probability that after $n$ selections ($n>1$), the product of the $n$ numbers selected will be divisible by 10.

Basically, I’ve been taking a break off olympiad math and been reading schilling. I was curious about whether I can apply this knowledge.

Comment: Who, why, which or what is "schilling" other than an ancient unit of currency in some Germanic countries? Aside from that, [probability theory as axiomatised by Kolmogorov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms) essentially reduces to the calculation of Lebesgue integrals. However, that theoretical fact is very important for some purposes, but doesn't help much with specific combinatorial questions like your example. Why not learn something about Lebesgue integration for its own sake?

Comment: I meant measures integrals and martingales. I did learn it because it was cool but it’d be nice if there was a way to use it on combinatorial problems. My doubt is, is there?

Comment: *Pace* ee cummings, capital letters and punctuation are quite useful. I think measure theory has a lot to say in probability theory, but not very much in specific combinatorial questions like your example. However, I am no expert in either subject.

Comment: The problem stated is about discrete events - no integrals involved.

Comment: I don't know about solving this problem using a Lebesgue integral, but you can certainly solve this problem via Markov chains

Comment: the Lebesgue integral theory is unrelated and unneeded to solve combinatorial problems

Comment: Could you give an example of a solution of a combinaorial problem by Lebesgue integration? I just wonder what you have in mind.

Comment: Yeah so that's what I wanted to be given. What sort of combinatorial/probability problems can be solved using lebesgue integrals and an example of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can utilize Markov chains to solve this problem.

Let $S_0$ be the state that the number isn't divisible by $2$ nor $5$, $S_1$ the state the number is divisible by $2$ but not $5$, $S_3$ the state the number is divisible by $5$ but not $2$, and $S_4$ the (absorbing) state the number is divisible by $10$.

This Markov chain generates the following transition matrix $P$: $$P=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{7}{9}&\frac{1}{9}&\frac{1}{9}&0\\ 0&\frac{8}{9}&0&\frac{1}{9}\\ 0&0&\frac{8}{9}&\frac{1}{9}\\ 0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ The probability the number is divisible by ten after $n$ selections equals $$p_{14}^{(n)}=e_1^TP^n e_4$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution by standard method.

The resulting number is not divisible by 10 if one of the numbers $2,5$ (or both of them) were never selected. The probability that this happens after $n$ selections is
$$
P_n=2\left(\frac9{10}\right)^n-\left(\frac8{10}\right)^n,
$$
and the probability that the resulting number will be divisible by $10$ is, respectively,
$$
1-P_n.
$$